# Open index.php using XAMPP localhost?

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, xampp, localhost

How can I open my index.php (file path: ***C:\Users\ammar\OneDrive\Desktop\WebDevelopment\PHP***) file in my browser through xampp localhost.

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HFRr.png)

Comment: move all of your php files from **C:\Users\ammar\OneDrive\Desktop\WebDevelopment\PHP**  to  htdocs folder located in the xampp folder

Comment: Or set up a virtual host, that has this directory as its document root …

Answer (score 0):

You will need a virtual host to serve that file to your browser, that will serve as your webserver.
Here you can find help to set up a virtual host:
[Virtual host](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-virtual-host-on-windows-10-for-wordpress/)

Comment: That is not the answer. As the question includes XAMPP, that is what serve as host. @Ammar, set up the folder path in XAMPP-settings, put you files in that folder and visit http://localhost/my-file.php in a browser.